# How to automatically detect columns that contain datetime in a Pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

[Dataframe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzw4b.png)

col1    col2

---

0  A       2017-02-04 10:41:00.0000000

1  B       2017-02-04 10:41:00.0000000

2  C       2017-02-04 10:41:00.0000000

3  D       2017-02-04 10:41:00.0000000

4  E       2017-02-03 06:13:00.0000000

I have multiple pyspark dataframes all with columns datatype as string. I want to filter out those column names which have datetime like patterns. Suppose, I have this above given pyspark dataframe with datatype of all columns as string. I want to write a code that automatically detects columns having values in datetime format. so, in the above dataframe, it should return col2 as output.
I have tried this in Python which worked but is giving 'type error' in Pyspark.

```
dt_list=[]

for x in df.columns:

  if df[x].astype(str).str.match(r'(\d{2,4})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\.(\d+)').all():

    dt_list.append(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

When string is transformed to timestamp and doesn't match timestamp format null is returned. In your code you need to check is something timestamp and than use if and depend on that leave as string or convert to timestamp.

```
df = spark.sql("select if(isNull(to_timestamp('I am normal string')), 'not date', 'date') as timestamp")
display(df)
```

[image]